# trap event when new wordpress post is added in a certain category

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to create a function which is triggered when a new wordpress post is added to the posts table for a particular category.

The function will grab the title of the post and add it to a new table called 'newsites' whose fields are (postid, title, questions, users) which is already created.

The 'questions' and 'users' fields will be calculated using a separate function already created.

If the title of the post already exists it will update the record and if not it will add a new record.

Any ideas how I can do this and especially, how do I catch a new post being added.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the Wordpress Filter/Action API.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks_2.0.x

There are filters for when a post is published, updated and changed status. From there all you need to do is add a relevant `add_filter`, `add_action` code.

Answer (score 1):

rmalinks wAfter following this tutorial, I couldn't get a couple of things to work. The permalinks will not work with the register_post_type() and arrays outlined in a function; I simply removed this and peorked fine

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a [MySQL Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) which fires after insert on `posts` and checks the field for a matching category. It can then `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` on `newsites`, assuming that `title` is a unique key (which ensures that the data is updated if it's already there).